# Virtual terminal 1 not working, system logs out instead

Tags: gnome, virtual-console

Posted this in the Ubuntu One forum, but because of little activity, I am posting the question here too:

**5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 13:51:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Desktop session and type is regolith, but Gnome behaves the same way. I have this problem on both my stationary and Thinkpad laptop.

Problem: While logged in, virtual tty3 etc will work when pressing ctrl+alt+F3, however tty1 will simply log me out, whether this is from a logged in gnome or regolith session or whether I am in tty3 or higher. Entering tty2 does nothing unless I am already in tty3.

The login screen which appears from attempting to enter tty2 or 1 will first not have the settings wheel where I can choose desktop session. Entering login credentials and clicking log in will give me a 2nd login screen where the settings wheel is present. Logging in now will work successfully.

Any advice on where to start?

Comment: IIRC GDM3 occupies tty1 and opens each session on the next free tty. So your first session is on tty2, the second on tty3, etc. The "login screen" without the wheel is probably Gnome's lock screen, not GDM's login screen.

Comment: just a fyi:  Ubuntu One is a login manager, and allows you to login to wiki/pad/forum/launchpad/fridge/etc & loads of other services in the Ubuntu world. You probably mean Ubuntu Forums, but you may also have asked on Questions (launchpad.net) or possibly other places that use Ubuntu.One to authenticate (*I use Ubuntu One to login to this site*)

Comment: @danzel Thanks. I believe you, but how could I find out for sure which screen is what?
Yes, I meant the Ubuntu Forums!

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of virtual consoles has changed since a few Ubuntu editions. Previously, tty7 would be assigned to graphical applications. All other tty's would be text consoles.

In Ubuntu 19.04, tty1 is assigned to GDM. Your running session is assigned to tty2. tty3 and others are text virtual consoles.

Indeed, because of this, swithing back to tty1 shows you the login screen. You are not logged out though: filling in your credentials on the GDM screen will bring you back to your running session.

So it now works a little bit differently. In order to use a virtual text console, move to tty3 and up. Move back to tty2 to resume your graphical session.

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, the Gnome lock screen and GDM login screen will not take me back to the "graphics" (is X a right term?). All applications will have to be relaunched so it really seems that I was logged out of the graphics.

So it seems both tty1 and 2 will give me the Gnome lock screen and entering credentials will give me the GDM (or something like similar). Simply heading to tty7 then will not function.

Comment: Could be buggy behaviour in 18.04. I remember that transitioning between the tty's would not always work properly for me. However, in my current trials on 19.04, it works seamless as I describe. Could also depend on the hardware, and in particular the graphical card.